# как коротко скопировать строку из идентичных таблиц

Tags: mysql, триггер

есть 2 идентичных таблицы, на одной висит триггер на insert
при срабатывании триггера содержимое переменной NEW вставляется в
INSERT строки для второй таблицы
есть способ записать этот insert в краткой форме, аля как-то так?

```
INSERT INTO <table>  (NEW.*) VALUES (NEW.*)
```

Comment: Боюсь, что нет. Правда после имени таблицы перечисление полей можно вообще убрать, главное что бы при этом в values были все поля и в том порядке в каком они объявлены в таблице

Comment: Ну и можно попробовать в триггере `after` сделать `insert into table select * from table 2 where id=NEW.id` но не знаю можно ли в mysql производить select в триггере на ту же таблицу

Comment: @Mike это сработало) а как насчёт update, можете подсказать?

Comment: Попробуйте replace. У него синтаксис как у insert, но он полностью удаляет запись если она уже есть и вставляет на место. Так что могут быть некоторые нюансы если вдруг есть ссылающиеся таблицы или что то в этом духе

Comment: я не могу использовать REPLACE ввиду того что у меня в таблице нет primary key т.к. мне нужно скопировать всё что есть в первой таблице без изменений

Comment: Ну тогда delete/insert. У вас же хоть и примари нет, ID же в первой таблице есть по которой вы запись уникально находите. delete конечно с OLD.id, insert с NEW. И индекс бы я на таблице все таки сделал по этому id а то при каждом update полное сканирование таблицы для поиска что менять напряжно для сервака ...

Comment: блин почему то подумал что примари кей всегда автоинкрементальный, сейчас глянул, оказалось не обязательно) оформите пожалуйста ответ выше как ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В триггере `AFTER` можно организовать вставку в другую таблицу в виде:

```
insert into table
 select * from table1 where id=NEW.id
```

Для изменения записи в триггере на UPDATE старую запись можно удалить и вставить новую:

```
delete from table where id=OLD.id;
insert into table
 select * from table1 where id=NEW.id;
```